# ImportError: cannot import name 'kafkaProducer'

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am using CentOS and have installed Python 3. Kakfa-Python has been installed using the command below.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install kafka-python
```

Then I started Python shell and tried to import kafkaProducer. But I got the error.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from kafka import kafkaProducer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'kafkaProducer'
```

Then I tried the code below to ensure that the module has not be imported.

```
>>> producer = kafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='host1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'kafkaProducer' is not defined
```

Most of the time, the "cannot import name xxxxxx" error is caused by a module name conflict, and I can fix it by renaming my own python script file. However, right now I am in a REPL and I have not created any file/module yet.

Comment: Try `KafkaProducer` instead of `kafkaProducer`

Comment: @drum Thanks for the help. That fixed the problem. My silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `KafkaProducer` instead of `kafkaProducer`